# Problema URLs Wordpress Htaccess

Tags: wordpress, htaccess, url-amigável

Tenho um projeto que tem um site institucional (domínio principal exemplo: cliente.com.br) e um blog com Worpdress em sub-domínio(exemplo: blog.cliente.com.br).

Tenho um htaccess no diretório raiz (site institucional) controlando minhas URL amigáveis e um htaccess no diretório /blog (meu sub-domínio).

O Htaccess do meu Wordpress é este:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Estava funcionando tudo certinho. Acontece que tive que alterar a estrutura, e meu sub-domínio *blog.cliente.com.br* passou a ser um diretório comum *cliente.com.br/blog* por limitações na hospedagem do cliente.

O que acontece é que:

- Quando eu acesso *cliente.com.br/blog* visualizo o blog certinho.
- Se navego até *cliente.com.br/blog/wp-admin* consigo acessar o administrador.
- Porééém, quando acesso um post como *cliente.com.br/blog/2017/11/27/a-porcelana-historia-e-beleza/* **não funciona** e carrega o conteúdo da index do meu domínio cliente.com.br.

Tenho que reescrever algo no meu htaccess do diretório /blog? Ou no meu htaccess do diretório principal? Não entendo tanto de modificações em htaccess e sempre utilizei somente o básico para minhas URLs amigáveis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido!

Fui no painel > Configurações > Links Permanentes e atualizei sua estrutura para recriar um novo arquivo .htaccess.

Corrigindo automaticamente e referenciando o diretório.

Ficou:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Que bom que resolveu, Aryana. Você pode aceitar sua própria resposta pra marcar como resolvida.